# MediaElementPlayer.js skinning and adding things to controlbar

Tags: mediaelement.js, video-player

I have studied the documentation, but not able to find some guide to alter the control bar, and the skinning, skinning can be done with css, but we need to add custom buttons and logo to the control bar,

can someone give a small hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to change the order of elements in control bar with feature array

```
 features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'],
```

how to add custom feature? is the question now